# Is there a way to suggest edits to a PR?

Tags: github, pull-request, gitlens

Is there a commonly used way to add small edits as code suggestions that the author of a PR can either accept or decline? Something similar to the way a Google Doc allows you to "Suggest Edits"

I'd like to speed up code reviews, and I think this would be a great teaching tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer - yes, there is.

You can add a block inside a fence marked with "suggestion":

````
```suggestion
throw new Exception("awesome!");
```
````

This will create a suggestion with code that can be applied automatically:
[image]

For additional details, see GitHub's documentation about [commenting on a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/commenting-on-a-pull-request) and [incorporating feedback](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/incorporating-feedback-in-your-pull-request).